# ng-repeat ignores immediate ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been working with Angular JS for long time now, but just now faced a strange issue where `ng-if` is simply gets ignored with `ng-repeat`.

This is the sample and simple code which doesn't work as expected

```
<ul ng-repeat="detail in details">
  <span ng-if="2 == 3"> <!-- This should block the next tags to execute-->
    <li>{{detail.name}}
      <ul ng-repeat="detailed in details.name">
        <li>{{detailed.prof}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </span>
  <span ng-if="2 === 2"> <!-- Instead this should get print -->
    Print this (Updated)
  </span>
</ul>
```

Here is my plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/xy4Qyd4tXm6kWROiaFVR?p=preview

Comment: So the result would be empty?

Comment: I am expecting this to print element under ng-if="2 === 2", that is "Print this".

Comment: The issue is from the angular version. If we use the latest version that doesn't give the problem. please check https://plnkr.co/edit/2qOtJK4UkjYqOrzWPote?p=preview

Comment: Use ng-show as mentioned by many people for the lower version. Please check https://plnkr.co/edit/2qOtJK4UkjYqOrzWPote?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this version

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

or use `ng-if` -> `ng-show`

Comment: Brief and to the point. Thanks a lot everyone else for the answer. Choosing this as preferred answer as it is the first answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is this:

```
 <div ng-show="'2' == '3'">
    <li>{{detail.name}}
       <ul ng-repeat="detailed in details.name">
         <li>{{detailed.prof}}</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
 </div>
```

Instead of using `ng-if` use `ng-show`.

Comment: I want ng-if to be inside ng-repeat. Because I need to compare while looping, exa. ng-if="detailed.prof === 'abc'". So I cant put this before. But I see ng-show can solves this issue. May consider adding this. BTW I haven't downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

> I have update you punker

Kindly take a look at [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/biPDTEXeMbzd2y4hDv3X?p=preview)

the problem is version  issue. also you convert it to number as like `(ng-if="+2 === +2")` try this code instead of yours

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="detail in details">
    <span ng-if="+2 === +3">
      <li>{{detail.name}}
        <ul ng-repeat="detailed in details.name">
          <li>{{detailed.prof}}</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </span>
    <span ng-if="+2 === +2">
      Nothing printed
    </span>
  </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```